# microservice architecture | endpoints and split entities

Tags: architecture, microservices, webapi

I'm working on a big project which is composed of many microservices(but one database),
for example, we have Agents microservice and Orders microservice
When we select an order some data of the order is an agent's name and phone,

Now the question is how to make the selection,
If I use a general `GetAgent()`  its returns a tone of data that I don't need.
I need just the name and the phone.

Write a new endpoint on Agents that return just name and phone,
Is it not overhead? (to write endpoint to every client property combination)

That situation is in many microservices.

So what can I do?
And if Odata or GraphQL can help here?

Comment: I think you need to check 12 factors of app and domain driven architecture first, before implementation. https://12factor.net/    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design

Comment: I too suggest to read idea and mechanics behind Microservices in general https://microservices.io/